# PNP Listview isnt lazyloading

Tags: spfx

I have implemented a listview control in my SPFX webpart. It is showing a memberlist with 205 members. But when I scroll down it is actually only showing 50..

When I look into console i get this warning, and I am sure that is the problem.

warn.js:14

```
   BaseButton property 'toggled' was used but has been deprecated. Use 'checked' instead.
```

Have anyone experienced the same?
I am using these versions

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.67.1",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.2": "^0.1.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.14.0",
    "@pnp/graph": "^3.2.0",
    "@pnp/sp": "^3.2.0",
    "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "^3.7.2",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "7.174.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1"
  },
```

Comment: Could you share the code you use to get the list of items, maybe? How many items does the query get - you can check this on the "network" tab (is it an active directory query? There may be limits to the number of items you can get in one page). The warning seems to be unrelated (and harmless), it is about some library still using a deprecated method.

Comment: I get 662 items but only 40 shown.. I found out, that it seems to be in workbench.aspx. When build for the appcatalog, it seems to work..